# Bootcamp Windows 7 external mic

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bootcamp, headphones, microphone

I have a 15 inch 2014 MBPr running windows 7 in bootcamp that I use for games. I bought a Razer Kraken headset due to it having a 4 pin 3.5mm jack and adapter for 2x3.5mm for compatibility with as many devices as possible.

The issue I am having is that when I plug the jack in all that comes up is the headset, no mic.

[image]
[image]

The problem with using the internal mic is that it picks up way to much noise from the internal fans to be usable.

Is there any way to fix this? Ive been googleing for the last hour or 2 with absolutely no luck.

I do have a USB audio jack I can use but that defeats the purpose of buying this headset in the first place.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue.  I found this thread which basically states, it is a known bug with Bootcamp.  There has been no fix for like 4-5 years:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3369017?start=15&tstart=0

I downloaded the latest version of bootcamp (5.1) to no avail :(

If you check the version of Bootcamp you are running (right click on the icon in the taskbar and click About Bootcamp) to see if you are running the latest.

Turns out I was running 4.0 and the latest for my laptop is 5.1.5621 and found here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3369017?start=15&tstart=0